# Agent can't be in several flowcharts at the time. At least two flowchart blocks are in conflict:

Tags: anylogic

Suppose I have the following supply chain model see model [model1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9buQB.png)

1. Agents are communicating with each other through a defined network and send messages to each other through ports. for example, demand is generated for customers through their ports and send as "orders" upstream to facilities. Upstream facilities send "shipments" to downstream facilities
   and stats are collected at each node.
2. The model seems to work for 2 echelons but when one facility is connected to two facilities downstream as desired I get the following error "Agent can't be in several flowcharts at the time. At least two flowchart blocks are in conflict"  [see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GewOG.png). Based on the description it seems the agent "shipment" is sent to two facilities at the same time.

My question is how could I avoid this conflict?

more information about each node:

1. Agents' "orders" enter through each node's port and are capture as Enter. take(msg), follow a flowchart, and exit as Agent "shipment" to each destination. Each agent "order" has a double amount and port destination. [see facility node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avTpj.png)

any suggestions please?

Comment: What is the logic that sends shipments to multiple locations at the same time? Is this intended behaviour or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that you do not send agents into a flowchart that is already in another flow chart, correct. This is bad model design.

One way to debug and find the root issue: before sending any message agent, check `currentBlock()!=null` and traceln the agent and the block. Also pause the model.

You can then see where you want to (re)send that agent that is already in some other flowchart block.

You probably send message agents out that are still somewhere else.

PS: For messages, you probably do not want to use flow charts at all but normal message passing. This avoids these pains here as you can easily send the same message to several agents. Check how message passing is done in the example agent models

Comment: thanks @benjamin for your prompt response. After doing some debug: 

-agent "Shipment" is sent downstream to all connected facilities, this is a current issue. The agent is supposed to go to the requested facility or customer node.  that's why the agent "order:" has a destination parameter "port". I tried to correct it by using msg. receive method but It gives an error related to " not applicable for the arguments". Even If I do not use a flowchart as you suggested I still have to send a msg to two separate connected facilities. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please open a new issue if you advanced on the problem (this is not a forum but a Q&A place :) ). No idea what you are talking about now, add some pics and descriptions to help us help you, see https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow .Also, please upvote the answer if it was useful, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: thank you @benjamin. I was able to solve my issue. As you suggested, I reviewed anylogic message passing and came up with this article  about defining custom contact network/link: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/agentbased/link.html#defining-custom-contact-networks--links  
It explained exactly what I need to send msg to specific agents.
thank you for the help, I have upvoted the answer :D

Comment: apparently, I cannot upvote yet, need 15 reputations to cast a vote :(